# Pass a Func<T> into generic method via reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates

I have a class that implements

```
class MessageBus
{
    void Subscribe<T>(Func<T,Task> onMessage) {...}
}
```

In my code, I want to dynamically subscribe with several different message types.
E.g. I have message type:

```
class Message {}
class MessageA : Message {}
class MessageB : Message {}
```

I write code similar to this:

```
class MySubscriber
{
    void Initialize()
    {
         var mb = new MessageBus();
         var mbt = mb.GetType();
         var subscribeGeneric = mbt.GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Subscribe" && x.GetParameters().Length == 1);

         var subscribeConcrete = subscribeGeneric.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Message1));
         subscribeConcrete.Invoke(mb, new object[]{ new Func<Message1,Task>(Handle) });
         // On this line I get exception TargetException("Type does not meet target type"). Message my be a bit different, on my system I see it in Russian.
    }
    Task Handle(Message msg) {}    
}
```

Of course in this example it does not make sens to call via reflection, but in real program I get typeof(Message1) dynamically, and I get an array of those types.
What am I doing wrong? If write all the same normally, it works (i.e. Handle(Message) successfully cast to Handle(Message1) and is getting called.

Update: so the code above is correct and should work. In my program, I simply had a typo, and was invoking the method on the wrong object.

Comment: You're finding the first method with *two* parameters... but your method only has *one* parameter... could you post a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Jon, this is a typo. Yes, the real method has 2 params, but it does not matter. I'll write a complete working reproducer soon.

Comment: After fixing the typos (`Length == 2` should be `Length == 1` I think, and `Message1` should be `MessageA`) it compiles and runs without error when I try it. Could you show us a minimal example that goes wrong?

Comment: You might need to include binding flags like `mbt.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)` (also, if this is a platform like Silverlight, you won't be able to reflect to get the method.) Also, what is the _exact_ error you're getting? Is it a null reference? Is it not finding the method? Is it failing to make it generic?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair `// On this line I get exception TargetException("Type does not meet target type"). Message my be a bit different, on my system I see it in Russian.`

Comment: @PLB Oh oops. Maybe I should have my coffee before reading StackOverflow...

Comment: Hm... When I wrote a minimal working sample, it worked too. Maybe the problem is inside EasyNetQ, a RabbitMq client which I'm using...

Comment: I'm thinking, and I'm probably wrong (still haven't had that coffee), that you're creating a `Func<Message1, Task>` but pointing it at `Task Handle(Message msg)` which might be an example of contravariance. (I may be wrong on that, haven't really dealt with contravariance yet) From a bit of googling, it looks like RabbitMQ (not sure about EasyNetQ though) is running .NET 3.0 which doesn't support that.

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov Is it feasible to get rid of the generic and just have the method work against a `Func<Message, Task>`?

Comment: Hmmm 2. Sorry guys. After creating my simple reproducer, that actually worked. I even added the real MessageBus implementation and it again worked. So now I have a separate working sample, will be looking why it fails in a complete program.

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov No problem! Progress has been made!

Comment: I found the cause of the prolem. It was very stupid. I was calling subscribeConcrete.Invoke(mbt) instead of subscribeConcrete.Invoke(mb). Fair enough it was throwing :)

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov That's why I prefer really long variable names. :) BTW, answer your own question so other readers could find out what has caused this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with help from comments.
I've created a separate minimal reproducer and it worked. Then examined original code and found a typo. So the basic idea was correct from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
public class Dispatcher<TTarget,TArgBase>
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Action<TTarget, TArgBase>> _handlers;

    public Dispatcher(string methodName)
    {
        _handlers = typeof(TTarget).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(m => m.Name == methodName)
            .Where(m => m.ReturnType == typeof(void))
            .Where(m => !m.ContainsGenericParameters)
            .Where(m =>
            {
                var pars = m.GetParameters();
                return pars.Length == 1 && typeof(TArgBase).IsAssignableFrom(pars[0].ParameterType);
            })
            .ToDictionary(m => m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType, m => BuildWrapper(m));
    }

    private static Action<TTarget, TArgBase> BuildWrapper(MethodInfo m)
    {
        var target = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTarget), "target");
        var dest = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArgBase), "destination");
        var castEvent = Expression.TypeAs(dest, m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType);
        var call = Expression.Call(target, m, castEvent);
        return Expression.Lambda<Action<TTarget, TArgBase>>(call, target, dest).Compile();
    }

    public bool Call(TTarget target, TArgBase evt)
    {
        Action<TTarget, TArgBase> handler;
        _handlers.TryGetValue(evt.GetType(), out handler);
        if(handler == null)
            return false;
        handler(target, evt);
        return true;
    }
}
```